# Prevent traceback in main

Tags: python, logging, error-handling, try-except

In my `main.py` module, I call a function `myFunc()` from `util.py`. In `util.py`, I handle the exception that `myFunc()` may throw, and call `sys.exit(1)`. However, I still get a Traceback print in my `main.py` module. Is there a way to simply catch the exception in `util` and not have to deal with any output in `main`, or is it better for me to catch the exception in `main` rather than in `util` ?

```
def get_token(token_name):

    token_handler = Tokens(token_name)
    try:
        token = token_handler.get()
    except TokenException  as e:
        logging.error("{error}".format(error=e))
        sys.exit(1)

    return token
```

Comment: can you paste at least the code which handle the exception ?

Comment: @PRMoureu updated.

Comment: @NishantRoy Can you modify util's code?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes I can. Would you advise removing the `try, except` from `util` and adding it to `main` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of design principle, but the general idea is to catch exceptions *only when you know what to do with it*.

Swallowing exceptions is not a good idea, because it makes debugging that much harder. Especially when you have critical code written like this with multiple calling points. Exceptions as generated inside the function should be re-thrown/re-raised to be handled by the code that called that function.

For example, you could consider modifying `utils.py` like this:

```
def get_token(token_name):
    token_handler = Tokens(token_name)
    try:
        token = token_handler.get()
    except TokenException  as e:
        # write to some log file if needed
        raise e

    return token
```

Similarly, your `main.py` would look something like this:

```
try:
    token = get_token(token_name)
except TokenException:
    ... # handle TokenException
except Exception:
    ... # handle any other Exception
```

This certainly makes for more robust code since you as the caller have control over the function you call.